# How do I delete a partition that I mistakenly created?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

I bought a Kingston USB drive, and after unsuccessful install by Windows (7) I went to Kingston's support webpage and followed the instructions of how to make it work. I assumed the problem was the drive's letter (the letter 'E' was taken by a different USB drive) so I tried to change it to 'F.' I don't even know if it makes sense, but I ended up with another [drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siV1J.jpg).

I tried to delete it from the [disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnFgd.jpg), but no success. Is my only option now is to format Windows? Is there another solution?

Comment: What happened when you right clicked on the partition (in the graphic representation of disk management) and picked "delete"?

Comment: @jdh: I got a prompt box that says "Windows cannot delete the active system partition on this disk."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete an active partition, so you'll need to mark a different partition as Active. You should be able to mark the C: as Active, then delete the offending partition. If you aren't able to from within Windows, then you may need to use a Live CD/USB.

Right click on the partition you want to mark as Active and select `Mark Partition as Active'.

[image]

[Microsoft Resource on Marking a Partition as Active](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/mark-partition-active#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: Holy cow... Just did what you said and got "bootmgr is missing." Luckily, I had a repair disc. After Windows got restored I was able to delete it. Thank you!

Comment: That wasn't what I expected to happen. It was probably due to your F: also being marked as the System drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `DiskPart` to remove the active flag on your partition and then delete your unwanted partition. For usage, see [the technet documentation for DiskPart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Your usage will probably be along the lines of `select volume X`, `active`,`delete volume Y` where `X` is a volume/partition you want to keep and `Y` is the offending partition you want to delete.